# PHP and suexec on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, php, suexec

I am trying to get [suexec](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html) working with PHP on Debian Stretch (Apache 2.4.25).

I have the Debian package's default set of modules loaded plus `cgid` and `php7.0`.

This is the `VirtualHost` block I'm using on my test system:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        SuexecUserGroup testuser testuser
</VirtualHost>
```

This works correctly with a simple perl script in `/var/www/cgi-bin` that prints the process's UID.  The script prints `1000`, verifying that suexec is working.  I also get the expected line in `suexec.log`:

```
[2017-07-28 11:54:27]: uid: (1000/testuser) gid: (1000/testuser) cmd: moo.cgi
```

However, when I use a similar PHP script, `suexec` is never called and the script runs as the Apache user.

How can I get suexec to work with PHP scripts?

Answer (score 0):

The enabled php7.0 module handles your PHP pages. Disable it, install *php-cgi* and enable that instead like

```
AddHandler cgi-handler .php
Action cgi-handler /usr/bin/php-cgi7.0
```